# drawbacks or tradeoffs of using explicitly sized types in C family languages

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, performance, portability

I am developing several C and C++ projects that need to be portable across several desktop and mobile platforms. I know it is important to use explicitly sized types `u32_t i64_`t etc when I am reading and writing data to disk.

Would it be a good idea to use explicitly sized types of all integer types to ensure consistent execution? I have heard that explicitly sized types can have performance impacts because processors are optimized for their expected `int` type etc. I have also read that a good strategy is to use explicitly sized types internally for class data members but not in interfaces.

Are there any best practices regarding explicitly sized types on data members and interfaces? (I am assuming that there would not be a huge difference between C or C++ in these situations, but let me know if there is)

Comment: As long as they are as or more portable than the alternatives when required, I would imagine there *isn't* a down side other than making sure you design it very well in the beginning so that later down the road you don't have to change your types or code.  The only downside might be that a 32 bit integer (i32b or whatever) might take up twice as much space as an `int` is required too.  But, I like to know how big my data types are, so I don't see that as a downside.  If I wanted >= 16 bits, I would use >= 16 bits, not 32.  Also, have you seen stdint.h?  Sounds like you're reinventing.

Comment: Ah, actually I missed a really obvious downside.  Incompatibility with other people's code.  I would imagine that your int32b or whatever would almost always be compatible implicitly with an `int`, but there could be cases where it would not be (and thus should not be assumed).

Comment: @Mehrdad Not sure if that was aimed at me or the OP, but if me, then yes, there is.  I was just thinking C.

Comment: @Corbin: Oh I was referring to the OP. Yeah there's stdint.h/cstdint that does pretty much what the OP wants..

Comment: Doesn't stdint doesn't give me uniform sized types right? it only gives me types of at least a minimum size so if int was bigger on one platform than another which it is in my case than my bin files wouldn't work on both right? or am i misunderstanding

Comment: @JustinMeiners: It has types like that, (`int_least8_t`, `int_least16_t` etc...), but it also has exact sized types (`int8_t`, `int16_t` etc...).  The difference is, the latter do not exist if you are on a platform that does not have types of those exact sizes.  But if that's the case, then your typedefs won't work either. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer

Comment: Ok so that handles the uniform size, but my real question is are there any drawbacks to using them for most of my variables?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The nice thing about the basic "int" type is that it will pretty much always be the fastest integer type for whatever platform you're currently compiling on.

On the other hand, the advantage of using, say, int32_t (instead of just int) is that your code can count on an int32_t always being 32 bits wide no matter what platform it is compiled on, which means you can safely make more assumptions about the behavior of the value than you could with an int.  With fixed-size types, if your code compiles at all on new platform Y, then it's more likely to behave the exactly same as it did on old platform X.

The (theoretical) disadvantage of int32_t is that new platform X might not support 32-bit integers (in which case your code would not compile at all on that platform), or it might support them but handle them more slowly than it would handle plain old ints.

The examples above are a little contrived, since almost all modern hardware handles 32-bit integers at full speed, but there did (and do) exist platforms where manipulating int64_ts is slower than manipulating ints, because (a) the CPU has 32-bit registers, and must therefore split up each operation into multiple steps, and of course (b) a 64-bit integer will take up twice as much memory as a 32-bit integer, which can put extra pressure on the caches.

But:  keep in mind that for 99% of the software people write, this issue is not going to have any observable effect on performance, simply because 99% of the software out there isn't CPU-bound these days, and even for the code that is, it's unlikely that integer-width will be the big performance issue.  So what it really comes down to is, *how do you want your integer math to behave*?

- If you want the compiler to *guarantee* that your integer values always take up 32 bits of RAM, and will always "wrap around" at 2^31 (or 2^32 for unsigned), no matter what platform you're compiling on, go with int32_t (etc).
- If you don't really care about wrapping behavior (because you know your integers will never wrap anyway, due to the nature of the data they are storing), and you want to make the code a bit more portable for odd/unusual compile targets, and at least theoretically faster (although probably not in real life), then you can stick with plain old short/int/long.

Personally I use fixed-size types (int32_t, etc) by default unless there is a very clear reason not to, because I want to minimize the amount of variant behavior across platforms.  For example, this code:

```
for (uint32_t i=0; i<4000000000; i++) foo();
```

... will always call foo() exactly 4000000000 times, whereas this code:

```
for (unsigned int i=0; i<4000000000; i++) foo();
```

*might* call foo() 4000000000 times, or it *might* go into an infinite loop, depending on whether (sizeof(int)>=4) or not.  Certainly it would be possible to hand-verify that the second snippet *doesn't* do that on any given platform, but given the likely-zero performance difference between the two styles anyway, I prefer the first approach since predicting its behavior is a no-brainer.  I think the char/short/int/long approach was more useful back in the early days of C, when computer architecture was more varied, and CPUs were slow enough that achieving full native performance was more important than safe coding.

Comment: note that overflow on signed ints is undefined, so if you want wrapping behavior, always use unsigned types.

Comment: Rust's [approach to types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/primitive-types.html) is for `u8`, `i32`, `u64`, etc. to be the primitive types.  There's `isize`/`usize` for pointer-sized integers, but otherwise only fixed-size.  So the language designers felt that it **wasn't important for modern hardware to provide implementation-dependent integers**, since 32bit is fast on everything that matters and big enough for most uses.  (Give rust a try if you're tired of C's refusal to standardize two's complement overflow/wrapping, or things like `popcnt`, arithmetic right shifts, rotates, etc. etc.)

Answer (score 6):

Use `inttypes.h` or `stdint.h`. It is ANSI-C, so it wll be supporte by any toolchain that aims to be ANSI compliant.

Furthermore, it still saves you the work of reinveinting the wheel.

The only thing you must do is

```
#include <inttypes.h>

uint32_t integer_32bits_nosign;
```

- One more concern about portability:
  So important as data width is **data endianess**.
  You must check the target endianess with standard macros:

  ```
  struct {
  #if defined( __BIG_ENDIAN__ ) || defined( _BIG_ENDIAN )
      // Data disposition for Big Endian   
  #else
      // Data disposition for Little Endian   
  #endif
  };
  ```

It is specially sensitiive if you use bit-fields.

---

EDIT:

Of course you can use `<csdtint>` as others suggested if you plan to use it on C++ only code.

Comment: Ok, so do you think it is a good idea to use them on for data members etc?

Comment: Your class interfaces are the most important contracts, so focus on them. And I would write interfaces with ints. As for storing them, do you have to? If not then use an int. If you **must** then specify the size. For storing data in files, make this as predictable as possible, so have an interface that does nothing but encodes and decodes so that your code does not have to care about endianness

Comment: @JSPerfUnkn0wn why would you say to make my interfaces use generic types?

Comment: Because `int` works, and there's little need to try to fix what isn't broken :) Your interfaces will be nice to work with, and will be intuitively obvious and fit in with what programmers are used to seeing. But most important of all, just choose one coding standard and stick to it. Then you can come back having experienced all there is when using different types, and feed your experience back to the community :)

Answer (score 1):

A rather nasty "gotcha" with fixed-sized types is that while they give the impression that code isn't dependent upon the size of "int", that's actually an illusion.  A piece of code like:

```
uint32_t mul(uint16_t a, uint16_t b)
{ return a*b; }
```

will have a defined meaning for all values of "a" and "b" on all platforms
where "int" is 40 bits or larger, and will also defined meaning for all values
of "a" and "b" on all platforms where "int" is 16 bits, though the meanings
will be different when the arithmetical product is 65535.  The authors of the
C89 Standard noted that while not required to do so, the majority of
implementations of that era defined their integer-math behavior such that most
signed operations--with a few particular exceptions--would behave identically
with their unsigned counterparts *even when the result was between INT_MAX+1
and UINT_MAX*--and thus on those compilers the behavior for all values of "a"
and "b" would match the behavior on machines with larger "int" types.  It has
become fashionable, however, for 32-bit compilers to generate code which will
break with values greater than INT_MAX since the Standard doesn't forbid them
from doing so.

Comment: @JustinMeiners: I wonder how I should best express the fact that code which relies upon sensible behavior for values INT_MAX+1 to UINT_MAX will *almost* always work, even with modern compilers, but small changes to the code might allow the compiler to see an "optimization" it had previously missed, so one can't rely upon any such code working unless one disables a bunch of useful optimizations in addition to the obtuse hyper-modern "optimizations".

Answer (score 0):

There are fast_ type of sized integer in stdint.h, the compiler will choose the fastest integer with required size in the platform, for example(extracted from stdint.h)

```
typedef signed char     int_fast8_t;
#if __WORDSIZE == 64
typedef long int        int_fast16_t;
typedef long int        int_fast32_t;
typedef long int        int_fast64_t;
#else
typedef int         int_fast16_t;
typedef int         int_fast32_t;
__extension__
typedef long long int       int_fast64_t;
#endif
```

Comment: The question is, fast for what?  For temporaries, `int32_t` is slightly faster than `int64_t` on x86-64.  (Smaller code size (REX prefix usually not needed), and faster multiply on pre-silvermont Atom).  And if you ever store them to memory, it takes 8B instead of 4B.  I think 64b `int_fast32_t` is a really weird choice on x86-64, but it's the choice they made.